# Appengine: Backend API Tutorial, cannot build project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I have completed the Java Tutorial for Google App Engine. 
Now I wanted to do the Backend API Tutorial, but I get errors..

I installed Maven and I was able to generate the project from the command line with maven as described in "Creating an Endpoints Backend Project". I have problems with the next step: [Configuring the Maven Project for Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/configure_pom).

Under the point "Setting required plugin configuration" it says "2. Locate and replace the default appengine-maven-plugin configuration entirely with the following: ", before they were talking about the pom file from "helloendpoints/helloendpoints-war".

--> But in that pom.xml-file from "helloendpoints/helloendpoints-war", I cannot locate that configuration... I found that in the pom file of "helloendpoints/helloendpoints-ear".

Question 1: Is this (in ear-folder) the pom-file that i shall edit or should there be  that configuration in the pom from the war folder?

However, replacing that code there or not both gives me an error when I invoke maven with "mvn install".

The error-message is the following: "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war  on project helloendpoints-war: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: basedir C:\Users...\helloendpoints\helloendpoints-war\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints does not exist".
And I can see that in "...\helloendpoints-war\target", there is no "generated-sources"-folder!

And this is where I am stuck now.

Question 2: Can all this be done without Maven and is there any tutorial for that? Because that is another source of errors and I had to deal with enough errors now... I just want to get an understanding of how the appengine works, how I can use it for my android app and then start from a WORKING basic-project, but I already had to deal with lots of errors. This is pretty frustrating, because I just wanted to do what is told in the tutorial and I still did not write any own code yet...

Question 3: In [the next part of the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api), are they using the m2e-plugin or anything? Because that was mentioned nowhere, but somehow you have to import that maven project into eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it without `Maven`.[This](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial) are simple tutorials from Google that shows you how to add a backend to an Android project.

Comment: well i already tried those other 2 tuts. The fist one, which is not really a tutorial and does not explain how to use app engine works now, but the second one gives me still errors.. When I create the CheckIn class and insert the code, I get errors, because I cannot import the following: 


import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

I guess I have to add a library, but how and which? Nothing of that said in the documentation of that tutorial

Comment: sorry for that project name (not meant against google, just against bugs), it is like my 1000th project now and I am out of names and after like 50 spent hours reaching nothing because of bugs, I am very annoyed... my new project is called pleaseNoMoreBugs, so you know what I am feeling like ... 
Trying to follow your suggestion now

Comment: worked for the error messages concerning javax, thx for that!
I still can't import com.google.appengine! I googled that, but I can't solve it. Which package is needed for that? And shouldn't that be generated automatically with the appengine-plugin?

Comment: Did you import the Google plugin to Eclipse?

Comment: Under Window-->Preferences-->Google-->Appengine I have the path pointing to the plugin

Comment: Not sure if that is a help, but i have
"C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.1\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.1\docs\javadoc\com\google\appengine\api\datastore"
and "C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.1" is in the Path from  Window --> Preferences-->Google-->Appengine.

Comment: I think you have the required plugin.But am not sure why you keep getting that error

Comment: Well I don't know either.. I run from one error into another all the time when solving an error by googling it. But I think i've installed everything correctly. Is this working on your computers? I mean is that a bug of that google plugin or is it just on my computer?
The only working projects are the Java Tutorial(use Maven) and creating an app engine connected android project. But there is not as much help as in the tutorials, so it is difficult to learn the app engine this way. As you already said, I should try to get this tutorial working in order to understand and learn the engine...

Comment: On a magical way, after restarting my computer this works now .. dunno wether to cry or to laugh ;-)
anyway, thx for your help and time!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because i need at least 15 reputation ;-)

Comment: Yeah.True.Happy coding.And try to be patient.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to delete this topic, because I switched to the tutorial without Maven, which has not much to do with my original post. That tutorial works now, but I cannot explain what solved it. I think this whole topic is more confusion and also wasted time for anyone else, who is trying to find an answer here.

Comment: You can do the delete yourself.or try to reword the question.to make it clearly and specific to your problem